# Cordova plugin for network information always return connection.type=UNKNOWN on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, cordova, network-programming, ionic-framework

I am trying to check the internet connection on my app.
When I launch the app on the iOS emulator, it doesn't work!
I have use this code: https://gist.github.com/welcoMattic/c6415563d6607fbedf3e

I have 2 problems:

1) When I debug, I see that $ionicPlatform.ready (line 16 of the code on github) is never fired. I've tried everything I know to understand why but I didn't find a solution.

2) I have then tried to make the code work without the $ionicPlatform.ready. But then I always get connection.type= Unknown. I have changed the code several times, I always get 'unknown'.

So I wonder,

1) Is it the simulator that doesn't support the plugin?

2) Is there a problem with the code or am I missing something?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: does it work on a real device?

Comment: I do not have an Apple developer account yet, so I can't test it on a real device. I would have definitely tried if I has the opportunity.

Comment: are you using angular?

Comment: Yes, I am using angular with IonicFramework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution (It is the small things that drives you crazy).

Here is the answer:

I was using the command: $cordova emulate ios
To emulate an app using the ionic platform: "$ionic emulate ios"

What can bring confusion is that your app will launch with "$cordova" and it will work but some functionalities won't. That is what confuses me.

Anyway...

If you had the same issue, be sure to remove the already ios platform obtained using "$cordova platform add ios" and "$cordova emulate ios" before trying with "$ionic emulate ios".

So, to solve the problem, there is only two simple steps:

1) Remove the iOS cordova platform (in the console tap):

```
$cordova platform remove ios
```

2) Add the IOs ionic platform (in the console tap):

```
$ionic platform add ios
$ionic build ios
$ionic emulate ios
```

That's it!